# UCD Deployment error - Application Process (my application process) could not be resolved - what is the fix for this

Tags: udeploy

UCD Deployment error - Application Process (my application process) could not be resolved

Unable to deploy Artifact from Jfrog getting below error
UCD Deployment error - Application Process (my application process) could not be resolved